# Android - Abrir Activity Aleatória

Tags: java, android

Bom, minha dúvida é  seguinte: é possível fazer com que uma função chame uma Activity Aleatória?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomIndex = r.nextInt(5); // Index aleatorio de 0 a 4

Class<?>[] activities = new Class<?>[]{
        Activity1.class,
        Activity2.class,
        Activity3.class,
        Activity4.class,
        Activity5.class
};

Intent intent = new Intent(this, activities[randomIndex]);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível.

O modo de se abrir uma activity no Android é através de *Intents*, como abaixo:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Parametros opcionais
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Nesse caso, a forma que acho mais interessante de se abrir uma activity aleatória seria pelo uso da função `nextInt()` da classe Random.

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.nextInt(numero de resultados possiveis) + resultado inicial;
// Por exemplo, gerar um numero de 65(incluído)-80(excluido), você usaria nextInt(80 - 65) + 65
```

Com a decisão aleatória feita, podemos lançar a Activity, você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
switch (randomNumber) {
    case 1: abre activity 1; break;
    case 2: abre activity 2; break;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Eu usei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click) e [esta outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029495/how-can-i-generate-random-number-in-specific-range-in-android).